# DataServiceCollection: undo remove exsiting item

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, change-tracking

I'm looking at WCF Data Services, particularly at change tracking implementation in `DataServiceCollection`.

Let's consider an undo scenario in application, which manages blogs and blog entries (each blog has many blog entries). I'm testing two sorts of undo operations:

- new blog entry was added (undo operation is to remove entry);
- existing blog entry was deleted (undo operation is to add entry).

Here's code sample:

```
var context = new BloggingContext(new Uri("http://localhost/WCFDataServicesDemo/"));
var blogs = new DataServiceCollection<Blog>(context.Blogs.Expand(b => b.Entries), TrackingMode.AutoChangeTracking);
var blog = blogs.Where(b => b.Id == 1).Single();

// new entry
var newEntry = new BlogEntry
{
    // some blog entry's properties
};

// add new entry
blog.Entries.Add(newEntry);
// undo add
blog.Entries.Remove(newEntry);

// existing entry
var existingEntry = blog.Entries[0];

// remove existing entry
blog.Entries.Remove(existingEntry);
// undo remove
blog.Entries.Add(existingEntry);

context.SaveChanges();
```

The first undo operation (add new entry, then remove it on undo) works fine.
The second undo operation (remove existing entry, then add it on undo) works asymmetrically.

This line:

```
blog.Entries.Remove(existingEntry);
```

marks corresponding entity as `Deleted` in context's change tracker, which is right. But this line:

```
blog.Entries.Add(existingEntry);
```

does nothing with change tracker (`existingEntry` remains in `Deleted` state), but, of course, adds item into collection.

Hence, when `SaveChanges` is called, this entry being deleted from database, but it remains in the collection at client side.

I've tried to handle this undo manually, by setting callbacks in `DataServiceCollection` constructor, but here I'm getting the same asymmetric behavior - `collectionChangedCallback` doesn't fire, when I'm trying to add item, which is marked as `Deleted`.

What am I doing wrong?
How to "restore" deleted item?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use Detach to undo changes. See this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/a944a15f-4a2f-424a-8222-584aad5eaf73

Comment: Sorry, I should mention, that undo operations is implemented in tiny framework, which I don't want to couple with data services. So, I need pure collection-based solution. Moreover, this look natural - if user adds deleted item, than he wants to restore it back. It's OK to work with data service context in `DataServiceCollection` callbacks, but not in the undo code.